# Средствами JavaScript изменить значение input'a

Tags: javascript

Можно ли, только средствами JavaScript (getelementbyname) изменить значение input'a найденного по имени например <input name='lex' value='' />?

Возможно есть способ найти этот элемент как-то иначе?

Хочу написать букмарклет, но у элемента кроме атрибута name и class ничего нет

Answer (score 2):

так, не http://jsfiddle.net/Rf8Dp/ ?

Comment: абсолютно так